# How to access the MySQL Database which is kept online through Java Swing Application

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I have developed an Java Swing Application with MySQL database for one of my client which runs on one computer and at one place and now he has the requirement such that he wants to see the Application remotely from other town. So In order to pursue this i have thought to install one more copy of the Software on another town from which my client is going to access renotely to the Application. So now i cant connect the LAN wires and MySQL Database has to be kept online 
So i have googled around about this that how to access the MySQL Database kept online but cud not find the solution cud anyone please tell me how cud i achieve this

Earlier for Single System we used to access the Database as shown below

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/SmartDiagnostics";
    String username="root";
    String password="";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConfigDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConfigDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return con;
```

Now what url do i need to pass in order to achieve this i mean to connect and access the MySQL Database kept online also is it possible to connect and access MySQL Database with Java Swing Desktop Application or is there any other way please do help for me.

Comment: instead of localhost use public IP address of the database server, it is very unsecure, but it will work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible access a MySQL Database remotely, but its disabled by default. You can look how to do this in [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html). So your connection url will change to:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://${public ip from machine where database is running}/SmartDiagnostics";
```

I hope it helps. :)